# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_Firebase.default.auth().currentUser.displayName') Firebase React Native

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

** Please Help Anyone. I can't get the log out of Firebase. It continues to give me an error. Here is my code below. ** `i want to log put it gives me error null is not an object (evaluating '_Firebase.default.auth().currentUser.displayName')

```
         import * as firebase from 'firebase';

         const firebaseConfig = {
         apiKey: "AIzaSyADgtLqQHs1KAlnMKUn8uM_vpasRUkWchw",
         authDomain: "reactnativefirebase-9ed38.firebaseapp.com",
         projectId: "reactnativefirebase-9ed38",
         storageBucket: "reactnativefirebase-9ed38.appspot.com",
         messagingSenderId: "117218702170",
         appId: "1:117218702170:web:94a6ad8eea017273c43963",
         measurementId: "G-2RN9L587XJ"
                                 };
              // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        export default firebase;


         import React, { Component } from 'react';
         import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
         import firebase from '../database/firebase';

         export default class LoginOut extends Component {
              constructor() {
                               super();
                               this.state = { 
                                               uid: ''
                                            }
                                             }

                              signOut = () => {
                              firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
                              this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
                                             })
                            .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }))
                                              }  

                                render() {

                                      this.state = { 
                               displayName: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName, ////Firebase 
                                  User Authentification /////
                             uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
                                }

                                return (
                                       <View style={styles.container}>
                                       <Text style = {styles.textStyle}>
                                       Hello, {firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName}
                                      </Text>

                                     <Button
                                            color="tomato"
                                             title="Log out"
                                              onPress={() => this.signOut()} ///Calling Sign Out 
                                               Function /////
                                           />
                                          </View>
                                         );
                                          }
                                       }
```

Comment: someone, please help me I am badly stuck in this error 

Comment: The error says `_Firebase.default.auth().currentUser.displayName`, but your code shows `firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName`, is it lacking a `default` right after the `_Firebase`?

Comment: it shows the same error